# Exclude parent row if any child rows meet condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table category and products and I'm doing filtering with many methods on the rows using full string text and `like`.

This is my data :

Table Category :

> ```
> Id  Libelle   Description
> 1   Animals   dogs
> 2   Kids      games
> ```

Table Product :

> ```
> Id  Name   Category_Id
> 1   aaa kkk   2
> 2   bbb kkk   2
> ```

There is a FK between these two tables.

This is my first query I select rows and then I want to exclude the row if `category.Libelle` OR `Category.Description` match some word :

```
    select distinct * from category cat JOIN product pro on pro.Category_Id = cat.Id
where (MATCH (pro.Name) AGAINST( 'kkk'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
AND
(concat(cat.Libelle , cat.Description) NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]]kids[[:>:]]')
```

Here the result is not correct it returns 2 rows except that must return 0 rows why ?

The second query I want the same purpose but I will check with `product.Name` :

```
    select distinct * from category cat JOIN product pro on pro.Category_Id = cat.Id
where (MATCH (pro.Name) AGAINST( 'kkk'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
AND
pro.Name NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]]bbb[[:>:]]'
```

Here I have as result one row that is it :

```
'2', 'kids', 'games', '1', 'aaa kkk', '2'
```

But I want to exclude that row also, so I want exclude the row of the category if any of the Name of list Product `pro.Name` associated with `Category_Id` contains exact word 'bbb', So I want a result of 0 row and not 1 row, How can I do it ?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: @Kendle 8.0.26.0

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your regex pattern, and replaced the **MATCH** function with **LIKE**.
Note that MySQL using standard regex since version 8. I have used the following elements in the regex pattern:
`^` beginning of line
`Kids` literal string
`$` end of Line
You may want to use
`\b` beginning or end of line (has to be escaped and becomes `\\b`)
`[Kk]ids` matches `Kids` and `kids`.

> ```
> create Table Category (
> Id int,
> Libelle   varchar(10),
> Description varchar(10));
> insert into Category values
> (1,'Animals','dogs'),
> (2,'Kids','games'),
> (3,'Kids plus','clothes');
> ```

> ```
> create Table Product (
> Id int,
> Name varchar(10),
> Category_Id int);
> insert into Product values
> (1   ,'aaa kkk',   2),
> (2   ,'bbb kkk',   2),
> (3   ,'bbb kkk',   1),
> (4   ,'bbb kkj',   1),
> (5   ,'bbb kkk',   3);
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   p.Id,p.Name, 
>   c.Id,c.Libelle,c.Description
> from Category c 
> JOIN Product p on p.Category_Id = c.Id
> where p.Name LIKE '%kkk%'  
> AND
> c.Libelle NOT REGEXP '^Kids$'
> AND
> c.Description NOT REGEXP '^Kids$'
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Name    | Id | Libelle   | Description
> -: | :------ | -: | :-------- | :----------
>  3 | bbb kkk |  1 | Animals   | dogs       
>  5 | bbb kkk |  3 | Kids plus | clothes
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1a99cca3b76f7dbf3af2126c4392c69)*

Comment: Here Like AND NOT REGEXP 'Kids' search if the word is contains in string but I want searching exact word match for that I'm using full text string and regexp with pattern